# Issue with merge TFS 2015 VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge

I'm new in TFS and I have a problem when I have to merge a file. Yesterday I have branched a project so that other people can work at the same time, today I've done some changes on one file of this project, also other people have done some changes on the same file on the branched project.

Now I want to put the changes done in the branched project into my code, but when I do a merge from the branched file into mine, TFS find some conflicts but allows me to "keep target branch version" or to "take source branch version".

In this scenario I have to choose between the changes that I've or the changes done in the branched project, is there a way to put both the changes in one file? Why the button "Merge Changes in Merge Tool" doesn't appear?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What are the file types involved? TFS doesn't allow merging of binary file types by default - I think there's an option to override it if TFS has detected it wrongly (e.g. a txt file with .exe extension)

Comment: Most of them are .cs or .resx file. I verified that all of them are not in binary format, they are all saved in UTF-8.
I cannot undestand why when I merge a resx file the button "Merge changes in merge tool" appears, when I merge a cs file it doesn't.

Comment: What's the result if you resolve conflicts with a newly created cs file? Try to do it on another machine and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you got conflicts when you do the merge operation. You should **first resolve these conflicts** take either the target or source version based on your requirement. **After you resolved the conflicts, you can then do the merge operation.**

In your case, since you want to put both the changes in one file. As a workaround, you could do a [**manually merge**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/merging#resolve-merge-conflicts-1) by selecting **Merge**, then entering the changes directly.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot understand how to do a manually merge. I can't see the button "Merge" anywhere.

Comment: @GiuseppeCecca  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/merging#resolve-merge-conflicts-1  You could see the gif in **resolve merge conflicts**,  select the file which have conflicts and select merge. In the merge page select both the difference in source and target with a  ✓ and the merge the changes and check in. Both changes will be included in target file.

Comment: I have seen the gif, but in the resolve conflict tab of visual studio I can't see the button "Merge", this is my problem. I only see "Take server branch version" and "Keep target branch version".

Comment: @GiuseppeCecca After go through more details. I think this maybe a  encoding conflicts. Give a try with the solution by *Simon Hardman*  in this similar question- [TFS not showing Option "Merge changes in Merge tool"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/329d9054-44a2-49b5-895c-d524e65f5761/tfs-not-showing-option-merge-changes-in-merge-tool?forum=tfsgeneral)